# How do find the right GLxx object for a given function in LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm just starting to learn the fundamentals of OpenGL via LWJGL. Every OpenGL function is implemented as a method on a `GLxx` class. The `xx` corresponds to the version of the spec when that function was introduced, such as `GL20` for functions added in OpenGL 2.0. So far, so good.

The difficulty comes when following tutorials or looking at code that is written against the C API. I'm finding myself having to either guess or Google the version for every single function that I want to use. This is quite time consuming.

Is there a quick way of finding out which version of OpenGL any given feature was introduced? (Or any other way of figuring out the right LWJGL class for a function?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference material on the [OpenGL website](http://opengl.org) is a good source for this. The function reference pages there have a "Version Support" section that details which version of the API the function in question is available in. [Here's the page for `glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xhtml), for example.

A machine-readable form of this data is available via the [API XML](https://www.opengl.org/registry/#specfiles), which would allow you to write a parser for the `supported` attributes if you were so inclined, and thus build a summary page. It's a bit of work though, you may want to start from [an existing tool that can parse this information](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home). Personally I'd stick to site-restricted searches against `opengl.org` for the functions you are interested in. Since you know the mechanical transformation used to go from version to LWJGL scope, you should be good to go; it's a little tedious, unfortunately, but it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fastest way has been "Find in files" feature of the IDE / text editor. Recursively searching for the function name from either LWJGL API documentation or source folder quickly reveals the correct class name. This is just a few key presses compared to switching to a web browser and searching from the reference pages.